# Little space at the bottom of a beamer block

Tags: beamer, block

I want to expand the space after the equation at the bottom of a beamer block to looks smooth.

I tried to use `\vspace{1in}`, `\leavevmode\hphantom{ }`, and `\vspace{0.1in}`. but it produces long vertical space

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert} % Commande pour obtenir la valeur absolue.
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\openintvl}{]}{[}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\usetheme{Madrid}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Differentiability }
 Determine whether each of the following functions is (a) continuous, and (b) differentiable.
 \begin{block}{Exercise}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}\rightskip\leftm
\item $f(x)=2x-5$
\item $f(x)=x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}x+1$
\item $f(x)=(2x+1)(x^{2}+1)$
\item $f(x)=\sin x\cos x$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2+\cos x}$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{x^{2}+7}{x+1}$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$
\item $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$
\item $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}+1}$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$
\item $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}$
\item $f(x)=\cos(2x)$
\item $f(x)=\sin\left(3x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$
\end{enumerate}
  \end{multicols}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two quick and more or less dirty solutions.

First case, very dirty, add an *hidden* `item` at the bottom of each column. 
Second case, a bit less dirty, but somewhat surprising, add a `\vspace{0pt}` after `\end{multicols}`

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert} % Commande pour obtenir la valeur absolue.
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\openintvl}{]}{[}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\usetheme{Madrid}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Differentiability }
    Determine whether each of the following functions is (a) continuous, and (b) differentiable.
    \begin{block}{Exercise}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \begin{enumerate}%\rightskip\leftm
                \item $f(x)=2x-5$
                \item $f(x)=x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}x+1$
                \item $f(x)=(2x+1)(x^{2}+1)$
                \item $f(x)=\sin x\cos x$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2+\cos x}$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{x^{2}+7}{x+1}$
                \item[]
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$
                \item $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$
                \item $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}+1}$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}$
                \item $f(x)=\cos(2x)$
                \item $f(x)=\sin\left(3x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$
                \item[]
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Differentiability }
    Determine whether each of the following functions is (a) continuous, and (b) differentiable.
    \begin{block}{Exercise}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \begin{enumerate}%\rightskip\leftm
                \item $f(x)=2x-5$
                \item $f(x)=x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}x+1$
                \item $f(x)=(2x+1)(x^{2}+1)$
                \item $f(x)=\sin x\cos x$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^{2}}$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{2+\cos x}$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{x^{2}+7}{x+1}$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$
                \item $f(x)=\sqrt{x+2}$
                \item $f(x)=\sqrt{x^{2}+1}$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$
                \item $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}$
                \item $f(x)=\cos(2x)$
                \item $f(x)=\sin\left(3x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
        \vspace{0pt}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the `multicols` package is not fully compatible with beamer. The notion of column balancing is difficult to apply to the frame concept of beamer.

I tried to devise a more "beamer-like" solution which uses the `columns` environment for the two column layout. Of course you have to waive some benefits of the multicols package like automatic column breaking.

To make it at least look like a continued column i defined two new enumerate environments which pass the item counter from one to another.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}

\newcounter{ContinueEnumerate}
\newenvironment{BeginEnumerate}{
    \begin{enumerate}%\rightskip\leftm
}{
    \setcounter{ContinueEnumerate}{\arabic{enumi}}
    \end{enumerate}
}
\newenvironment{ContinueEnumerate}{
    \begin{enumerate}
        \setcounter{enumi}{\arabic{ContinueEnumerate}}
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Differentiability }
    Determine whether each of the following functions is (a) continuous, and (b) differentiable.
    \begin{block}{Exercise}
        \begin{columns}[t]
            \column{0.5\linewidth}
                \begin{BeginEnumerate}
                    \item $f(x) = 2x-5$
                    \item $f(x) = x^{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}x+1$
                    \item $f(x) = (2x+1)(x^{2}+1)$
                    \item $f(x) = \sin x\cos x$
                    \item $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{x^{2}}$
                    \item $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2+\cos x}$
                    \item \label{x} $f(x) = \dfrac{x^{2}+7}{x+1}$
                \end{BeginEnumerate}
            \column{0.5\linewidth}
                \begin{ContinueEnumerate}
                    \item $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}$
                    \item $f(x) = \sqrt{x+2}$
                    \item $f(x) = \sqrt{x^{2}+1}$
                    \item $f(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}$
                    \item $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}$
                    \item $f(x) = \cos(2x)$
                    \item $f(x) = \sin\left(3x+\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)$
                \end{ContinueEnumerate}
        \end{columns}
    \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```